# canvas.drawLine doesn't work smoothly

Tags: android, draw, android-drawable

I want to draw simple line if the condition is true. but it dosn't work exactly after textview's update.sometimes I should pause the phone and reopen it, to see the line's changes. I want drawStep() draw line, at the same time that testview is updating...
what can I do for it?

```
 ....if (condition) {
                 txSteoCounter.setText("counter"+counterr);
                 drawLine();
                }...

 private void drawLine() {
    float x1 = (float) ( x0+200 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(-20)));
    float y1 = (float) (y0+200 * Math.sin (Math.toRadians(-20)));
    canvas.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1, paint);
    x0=x1;
    y0=y1;
    }
```

Comment: invalidate() the drawing control when the textview is updated.